# Updating Multiple Column on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update `members_roosevelt` table `ACCOUNT` column starting with 3000+ value I also want to update `ACCOUNT` column on `loan_roosevelt` table that is related to my `member_roosevelt`. What's wrong with my query? Thank you!

```
$query1     =   "SELECT ACCOUNT
                FROM
                    `members_roosevelt`";
$result_q1  =   $link->query($query1) or die($link->error);
while ($obj =   $result_q1->fetch_object()) {
    $members[] = $obj->ACCOUNT;
}
$ids =  implode(',', $members);
$sql =  "UPDATE `members_roosevelt` as `memb`
        JOIN    `loan_roosevelt` as `loan`
        ON      `memb`.`ACCOUNT` = `loan`.`ACCOUNT`
        SET 
            (`memb`.`ACCOUNT`,
            `loan`.`ACCOUNT`) = CASE ACCOUNT";
foreach ($members as $id => $ordinal) {
    $sql .= sprintf("WHEN %d THEN %d ", $ordinal, (3000+$id));
}
$sql .= "END WHERE memb.ACCOUNT IN ($ids)";
$link->query($sql) or die($link->error);
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, it starts with a SELECT

Answer (score 0):

```
SET (`memb`.`ACCOUNT`, `loan`.`ACCOUNT`) = CASE ACCOUNT...
```

This is simply not part of SQL syntax. You can't set two columns at a time like this. The left side of an assignment operator must be one column.

A better solution is to use a session variable.

```
SET @acct = 3000;

UPDATE members_roosevelt as memb
JOIN   loan_roosevelt as loan
    ON memb.ACCOUNT = loan.ACCOUNT
SET memb.ACCOUNT = (@acct:=@acct+1),
    loan.ACCOUNT = (@acct);
```

This way you don't have to run the SELECT query at all, and you don't have to create a huge UPDATE statement with potentially thousands of WHEN clauses.

Demo: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1764/1)